# Block a new item in a list if they already there two times

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, microsoft

please could help me ?

I would like to know if I can block the completion of a new item in the Sharepoint list, if this item already exists 2 times in the list.

I know I can block to exist unique values.

however I needed this item to be able to be accepted twice and then no more

Comment: Have you tried the workaround below? Does it meet your requirements? As there is no such function at present, to address your concern about the situation, we’d suggest you go to feedback on this issue, this is the best platform to let us hear from you and make our products and services better for you and others. The more votes, the easier it is to be seen. https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB way to do so.

**Approach 1:**

Create Power Automate with Item Adding Trigger and if based on your logic if item is added third time then delete it. Using this approach Item will be still added in the list and Power Automate will delete it.

**Approach 2**
You want to really prevent uses to add item from UI itself then you can create SharePoint Remote Event Receiver with trigger `Item Adding` where you can write your own logic and cancel event based on your request so that it will not allow to add item.

Following are some helpful links to start with Remote Event Receiver in SharePoint Online:

- [Event Receiver Samples](https://github.com/pnp/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.EventReceivers)
- [Create Event Receiver - Step by step guide](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/create-remote-event-receiver-sharepoint-online/)

You code should look similar to below:

```
public class EventReceiver1 : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
       /// <summary>
       /// An item is being added.
       /// </summary>
       public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           base.ItemAdding(properties);
         
           string title = properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString();
           
        
           // Your logic business logic will go here to query existing list items and check whether same item is exist two times of not
           bool isExistTwoTime = ValidateWhetherItemExistTwoTimes(title);
           
           if(isExistTwoTime)
           {
                properties.Cancel = true;
           }
          

       }


    }
```